# javascript / react charting package that supports image inside tooltips on hover?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, data-visualization

I have been using plotly but it doesn't support images or other custom designs inside the hover tooltip.

What javascript / react packages have highly customizable tooltips? I just need it for a scatter plot and bar chart

Comment: i think no one suggest any library here... please share your codes here and people will help you to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

I think [Apache ECharts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html) might help you on that, it is really customizable (open source!) and has good documentation.

Some links for the stuff you are looking to work on:

- Scatter Plot examples: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/index.html#chart-type-scatter
- Bar Chart examples: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/index.html#chart-type-bar
- Tooltip documentation: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Recharts seems to have a custom tooltips supported, should work:

https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomContentOfTooltip